# Rails Undefined Method when called in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

In my controller for Bulletins that are posted I have this:

```
 @master_settings = load_master_settings(Rails.root)
  BulletinMailer.bulletin_email(params[:bulletin][:attachment].path, @master.get_alias_email).deliver
```

The master object is set from a Datasources.xml file, and in a configuration loader file it sets it using:

```
doc.elements.each("DEFINITIONS/MAILGUN_THINGS") {|element|
  master.set_alias_email(element.attributes["ALIAS_EMAIL"])
}
```

Then within an application_helper.rb I have these methods to set the attributes of the master object:

```
def set_alias_email(val)
  @alias_email = val
end

def get_alias_email
  @alias_email
end
```

When I try to send mail and put the alias email directly into the bulletin_mailer.rb file it works, however when I try to pass in a call to the alias_email attribute of the master object, the mail sends but does not arrive in my inbox indicating to me that something either isnt being stored or called correctly.

The error I get is this:

undefined method `get_alias_email' for nil:NilClass at the line that says:

```
BulletinMailer.bulletin_email(params[:bulletin][:attachment].path, @master.get_alias_email).deliver
```

So what is going on?

Comment: You have created a variable `@master_settings`, but used another -`@master`

Answer (score 0):

You've loaded settings into `@master_settings`, but are trying to access `@master.get_alias_email`. The `@master` instance variable is `nil`.

Comment: here is how its getting set in the configuration loader helper:

Comment: doc.elements.each("DEFINITIONS/MAILGUN_THINGS") {|element|
      master.set_alias_email(element.attributes["ALIAS_EMAIL"])
    }